# How to use two button on a single page doing different function jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I select the button so it runs independently? When I click on a single button, both the function get run and if I give the id to the button the select the button by id, then nothing happens.

```
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("#page").fadeOut("slow",function () {

        })
    })

    $("button").click(function () {
        if($("#toggle").css("display") == "none"){
            $("#toggle").fadeIn();
        }else($("#toggle").fadeOut())
    })
```

Comment: Selecting by ID is correct in this case.  Please post the html for the 2 buttons, with IDs, and change the code to when you tried that, so we can help you fix it.  It was probably something minor.

Comment: try to use different selector for both buttons

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="submit" id="one">one</button>
<button type="submit" id="two">two</button>


   $("one").click(function () {
        $("#page").fadeOut("slow",function () {
        })
     })

 $("button").click(function () {
        if($("#toggle").css("display") == "none"){
            $("#toggle").fadeIn();
        }else($("#toggle").fadeOut())
    })
```